# Maven failed to execute goal compile

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-compiler-plugin

I am compiling a simple maven application using `mvn compile` on Solaris server from terminal and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven-demo: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
```

this is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                 <version>3.6.1</version> 
                 <configuration>         
                     <fork>true</fork>
                     <source>1.8</source>
                     <target>1.8</target>
                     <executable>/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0</executable> 
                 </configuration> 
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to the question.

Comment: The error message in the question is already the complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<executable>` is not `javac`. Instead of the directory, you need to specify the complete path.

Comment: it shows the same error after i added /bin/javac to the path

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you do _not_ fork the compilation?

Comment: this is the error if i don't fork:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven-demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: This could be the general problem. Maybe your Maven runs on a JRE?

Comment: Make sure that your JAVA_HOME and your PATH are set correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, At the end I found a problem with the javac file and I re-downloaded the jdk and it worked